# Linking libmodbus in CMake project under Windows (CLion IDE)

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, clion, libmodbus

I use CLion IDE with MinGW toolchain for my project.
I need to link libmodbus in CMake project in file CMakeLists.txt.
How can I do this?

I have installed libmodbus using Vcpkg GUI in CLion IDE on windows.
There is no options to add libmodbus to file CMakeLists.txt from Vcpkg GUI.

Comment: Have you tried target_link_libraries ?